# Using a list of indexes to delete from a another list giving me index out of range error - why?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am comparing two lists and deleting the first duplicate instances when there is a match and then moving on.  I know there are a lot of duplicates between these lists so I cannot just use list comprehension or anything like because I need to see which side has more instances, I'm basically just set subtracting the shared elements from both lists.

Heres my code:

```
toDelFromrbIndex = []
toDelFromabIndex = []
for rbIndex, (barcode, timestamp, prepack, workorder) in enumerate(restoredBottles):
    for abIndex, (idx, bcode, tstamp, tableName) in enumerate(allBottles):
         if barcode==bcode and timestamp == tstamp:
             #Remove from both lists
             toDelFromrbIndex.append(rbIndex)
             toDelFromabIndex.append(abIndex)

 for index in toDelFromrbIndex:
     del restoredBottles[index]

 for index in toDelFromabIndex:
     del allBottles[index]
```

Prior to this I was deleting them in place where 'toDelFromrbIdnex.append(rbIndex)' is and realized that is messing up my iterations, possible skipping items.  So I store the index first and then later just delete them all from both lists.

However, this `for index in toDelFromrbIdnex: del restoredBottles[index]` is giving me an `index out of range` error, why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are deleting indices from smallest to largest. Each deletion shifts elements to the right of the deleted index down one step, so what was at index N moves to N - 1.

In the end, the last indices you are trying to remove may now point outside of the list. The following also throws an `IndexError`:

```
foo = [17, 42]
for index in (0, 1):
    del foo[index]
```

because first we delete `17` at index `0`. Deleting the first element means that `42` then becomes the element at index `0`, and there is nothing at index 1 any more.

You need to delete the highest index *first*, so handle your indices *in reverse*:

```
 for index in reversed(toDelFromrbIdnex):
     del restoredBottles[index]

 for index in sorted(toDelFromabIdnex, reverse=True):
     del allBottles[index]
```

I sorted `toDelFromabIndnex` because you can end up adding ids to that in arbitrary order.

On an additional note: you are currently matching your 'bottles' very inefficiently. You are using a nested loop, so for N `restoredBottles` entries and M `allBottles` you are making O(NM) tests. As either list grows, you increase running time quadratically. For example, for N = 100 and M = 1000, you make 100.000 comparisons, for N = 200 that becomes 200.000 comparisons, or change M to 5000 and you need to make 500.000 comparisons.

If you use an intermediary dictionary, you can reduce this to O(N + M) steps:

```
# mapping from barcode and timestamp, to index in restoredBottles
bcts_idx = {}
for i, (bc, ts, *_) in enumerate(restoredBottles)
    bcts_idx.setdefault((bc, ts), []).append(i)

toDelFromrbIndex = []
toDelFromabIndex = []
for abIndex, (idx, bcode, tstamp, tableName) in enumerate(allBottles):
    for rbIndex in bcts_idx.get((bcode, tstamp), ()):
        # Remove from both lists
        toDelFromrbIndex.append(rbIndex)
        toDelFromabIndex.append(abIndex)
```

Comment: I also just realized I was deleteing on the index of the list, but I wanted the values in side, so I have to do `for i, value in enumerate(reversed(toDelFromrbIdnex)): del restoredBottles[val]`

Comment: @bjk116: no, you definitely stored indices (generated by `enumerate()`) in your lists. You don't have pairs of indices and values.

Comment: @bjk116: and you can't use `del restoredBottles[value]`, because a value is not an index.

Comment: Oh you're right, see on the second loop its still actually failing for some reason.   You know what it is, it's not necessarily going to be in order based on my logic, I have to sort it first.

Comment: @bjk116: yes, indeed, you are adding indices to that in arbitrary order. I added the sort.